# How can I access a variable in another class?

Tags: xcode, class, swift, var

I have a start screen with a log in button and a register button. Both lead to the same view controller, but its interface is based on a variable.

How can I make my startviewcontroller change this var, that can currently only be accessed from the mainviewcontroller?

Answer (score 1):

I'm temped to say "just like you get access to any other classes properties. However, given you haven't shared any code it's may not be as simple. But in general you will need to have a pointer to  an instance or shared instance (singleton) of your mainViewController. And of course those variables need to be public.

Comment: The variables could be internal as well, so I would say they shouldn't be private.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to declare that variable global outside any class just below the `import` statements. You will be able to use the variable anywhere in your code.

```
import UIKit

var myGlobalVariable: Int
```